# Is there a comma in "one easy place"?

Tags: adjectives, commas, numbers

Which of the following is correct? If both are acceptable which is preferred?

> Our product lets you manage all of your stuff in one easy place.
>
> Our product lets you manage all of your stuff in one, easy place.

Comment: Although there _is_ a difference here: 'one' is not classified as an adjective. Determiners and numerals always precede adjectives and should not be followed by a comma. 'One' and 'easy' cannot be considered to be in any way coordinate.

Comment: Since they *aren't* both adjectives, and because the answer on the linked question doesn't address placing commas between determiners and attributive modifiers, this is certainly not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @snailboat I'll leave the close-vote; the questions  are to some degree related. The situation is far easier with determiners / numerals and prenominal adjectives: commas are not used between a numeral or determiner and an adjective. *many, green leaves // * a, red book // a lot of, brown bread // *one/1, red book //  *12/a dozen, easy places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the option with comma is not acceptable. The adjectives modify the word **place** in a different way. They are not "coordinate adjectives". There's a simple two-step test for that:

1. Can we place **and** between the adjectives? (Note: "one" is not strictly an adjective)

> Our product lets you manage all of your stuff in one **and** easy place.

No.

1. Can we change the order of adjectives?

> Our product lets you manage all of your stuff in easy one place.

No.

Thus, there should be no comma between your adjectives. See [the subsection in Wikipedia's article on Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Between_adjectives):

> [image]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I was 100% sure they had been but I'm feeling under the weather and am now spending my time refreshing my grammar knowledge. Posting an answer is a good way of doing that. (0:

Comment: Sorry; ran out of time searching for a better example. Coordinate and cumulative adjectives and the tests for differentiating have been covered here before. As has the difference a comma makes if included in say 'a novel, industry-inspired problem' {= a problem that is both novel and industry-inspired} and 'a novel industry-inspired problem' {= a new member of the set of problems inspired by industry}. // Note also that **'one' is not an adjective**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - thank you! I'll read up on cumulative adjectives.